# How to write unit test for a subscribe function with filter in Angular 2?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine

Right now I am writing an unit test for this kind of situation like below:

```
public div: HTMLDivElement;
public currentEvent: EventType;

public listenToRender() {
    this.adsService.render.filter((event: EventType) => {
            return this.div.id === event.slot.getSlotElementId();
        }).subscribe((event: EventType) => {
            let custom_event = new CustomEvent('render', {
                detail: event
            });
            this.currentEvent= event;
        });
}
```

During the unit test, I mock the render with subject, but I don't know how I can make it pass the filter

```
return this.div.id === event.slot.getSlotElementId();
```

and go to the subscribe function.

```
class MockAdsService {
   render = new Subject();
}

class MockEventType {
   name: 'test_event';
   slot: {
      getSlotElementId = function() {return 'test_id'}
   };
}

describe('test', () => {
    let mockAdsService: MockAdsService,
        mockEventType: MockEventType;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockAdsService = new MockAdsService();
        mockEventType = new MockEventType();
    });

    it('listenToRender fired correctly', () => {
        mockAdsService.render.next(mockEventType);
        component.listenToRender();
        expect(component.currentEvent).toEqual(mockEventType);
    });
});
```

Do I need to set up something in subject.next for passing the filter?

Comment: Might be better to use `spyOn` instead of `subject`. Try `spyOn(service.render, 'filter').and.returnValue(Observable.of(expected_data))`

Comment: Thank you, Sasxa. You save my day! After I type `spyOn(service.render, 'filter').and.returnValue(Observable.of(mockEventType))`, the filter using the `mockEventType` I create when I run `listenToRender()`, then go to the `subscribe`

Comment: @Sasxa Can you explain why spyOn can pass the value to the `filter`?

Comment: Spy essentially replaces whatever it spy's on with what you provide as return value. Check jasmine docs for more info...

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. You're subscribing your component **after** your event has already happened. It's too late for cold observable. Just switch `render.next()` and `component.listenToRender()` calls and everything should work just fine:

```
it('listenToRender fired correctly', () => {
    component.listenToRender();
    mockAdsService.render.next(mockEventType);
    expect(component.currentEvent).toEqual(mockEventType);
});
```